# Using Pa11y with Supertest

Tags: accessibility, supertest, pa11y

What is the best way to use Pa11y with Supertest?  Something like:

```
describe ('my page', function () {
    it ('is accessible', function () {
        request (server).get ('/').expect (function ({ body }) {

            // How to run Pa11y here?

        });
    });
})
```

Comment: pa11y is for testing accessibility and supertest for HTTP node servers. I'm not sure why you would want to test those 2 things together.

Comment: @MatthewBlewitt A Node server can return an HTML page.

Comment: Sorry what I meant is that you might not need super test at all for this as pa11y can ping url's.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up going with a separate test script using pa11y-ci when I struggled with this method.

Comment: Yeh, I've found it to be a more flexible package, plus you get all the informative CLI errors. Good reference here https://bitsofco.de/pa11y/#doingmorewithpa11y

Comment: Just out of interest how did you setup pa11y-ci to run with a local server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not using `supertest` at all for these accessibility test as `pa11y` can ping url's directly.

```
const pa11y = require('pa11y');
const request = require('supertest');
const mocha = require('mocha');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const server = require('./server');

const url =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
    ? 'http://localhost:3000'
    : 'http://example.com';

describe('my page', function() {
  it('is accessible', function(done) {
    pa11y(`${url}/`, function(err, results) {
      expect(results.issues).to.be.empty;
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This is nice. Thanks!